# How to interpret tregex for clauses

Tags: parsing, pattern-matching, stanford-nlp

I am looking at the source code for [L2 Syntactic Complexity Analyzer](http://www.personal.psu.edu/xxl13/downloads/l2sca.html)

and it had a tregex expression for clause as:

> S|SINV|SQ [> ROOT <, (VP <# VB) | <# MD|VBZ|VBP|VBD | < (VP [<#
>   MD|VBP|VBZ|VBD | < CC < (VP <# MD|VBP|VBZ|VBD)])]

I am reading tregex syntax from this [link](https://nlp.stanford.edu/~manning/courses/ling289/Tregex.html) but am not confident that I understood the `Boolean relational operators` correctly, specifically does the second part of this tregex:

> **VP** [<# MD|VBP|VBZ|VBD | **< CC < (VP <# MD|VBP|VBZ|VBD)**]

mean

> (VP <# MD|VBP|VBZ|VBD) OR **((VP < CC) AND (VP < (VP <# MD|VBP|VBZ|VBD))**)

verb phrase that contains both a cc and vp (with md vbp vbz vbd)

Or

> (VP <# MD|VBP|VBZ|VBD) OR **(VP < (CC < (VP <# MD|VBP|VBZ|VBD))**)

verb phrase that contains a cc that contains a vp

Comment: You should refer to this power point for better understanding Tregex.  Link: https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tregex/The_Wonderful_World_of_Tregex.ppt

Comment: Let me know if you can't determine the answer to your question from that powerpoint, I think your question is beyond my knowledge off the top of my head!

Comment: Ok I attempted to answer.

Comment: Ultimately you probably need to directly test an example to verify my interpretation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In tregex (following earlier tgrep languages) a clause `A op B op C op D` always means `A op B AND A op C AND A op D`. If you want the opposite, you need to use parentheses as in Example 1: `A op (B op (C op D))`. So in the second disjunct of the original message, the VP has to contain a CC and another VP headed by a word of the indicated part-of-speech (`<#` is the "headed by" relation). So the answer is basically the former interpretation, with the one added constraint that the first VP in each conjunct of the second disjunct has to be the same VP node.

Answer (score 0):

Chris's answer is correct...

Full slides here:

https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tregex/The_Wonderful_World_of_Tregex.ppt

Comment: No, it's the former. In tregex (following earlier tgrep languages) a clause A op B op C op D always means A op B AND A op C AND A op D. If you want the opposite, you need to use parentheses as in Example 1. So in the second disjunct of the original message, the VP has to contain a CC and another VP headed by a word of the indicated part-of-speech (`<#` is the "headed by" relation). So the answer is basically the former, with the one aded constraint that the first VP in each conjunction of the second disjunction has to be the same VP node.